# Once-only thud knock when open throttle

Tags: engine, motorcycle, yamaha

I have a 1997 Yamaha TRX850.

When I open the throttle I'm hearing a thud knock sound near the left crankshaft cover. That sound does not always appears and I can't find any correlation between appearances.

Clutch and speed of opening the throttle didn't affect that sound.

In the meantime, the engine works perfectly well and has never been opened since 1997. I have changed the oil and antifreeze recently and seems like the motorcycle in a very good condition.

Is that OK for a TRX?

If not, what should I check to get rid of that sound?

Maybe it would be better to not open the engine if it works well?

**UPD1:**

The sound appears only once in the beginning of a process of opening the throttle. So the flow is as follows:

```
engine idle working -> beginning of opening the throttle -> BANG -> continue the process of opening the throttle (no thud knocks further)
```

The thud knock sound happens simultaneously with the roar of the engine only once.

The sound is very similar to the sound of smashing two heavy steel hammers together except it more thud.
I discovered it only after the 4 months of owning. It's not so easy to hear because of the engine's roar. Only if trying to hear it specifically.

**UPD2:**

Here is the link to video https://www.dropbox.com/s/55omtvm9bpccy5e/20160419_175448.mp4?dl=0

That sound appears on

- 0:10
- 0:40
- 0:56

Hope you will recognize it

Comment: Can provide a more detailed description of the sound and when it occurs?  Can you consistently create the sound under certain circumstances?  If you don't use the clutch and open the throttle all the way in first gear, second gear, third gear, and so on can you re-create the sound?  Welcome to the mechanics SE site!  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for a response! I've updated the post and tried to be more specific. Right now motorcycle is on winter storage. I will have possibility to recreate the sound and test motorcycle with gears shifting next week and will update the post right after that.

Comment: Nice update.  So this is very, very low in the RPM range, just off idle if I understand you correctly.  If it goes back to idle and you begin to open the throttle can you ever get it to do it again?

Comment: Is your chain adjusted correctly? could it be the chain taking up the slack/wear and then once under tension it doesn't make the same noise any more?

Comment: @DucatiKiller, yes, if I open the throttle again there is a possibility to hear the sound  again. As I said I can't figure out a correlation between appearances. It may or may not happen.

Comment: @Mauro, no, I don't think so, the sound appears on engine's idle working.

Comment: from what I understand you are not in gear, the engine is idling and you blip the throttle and hear the sound, sometimes.  Do I have this right?

Comment: @DucatiKiller, yes, exactly. Sorry, English isn't my native language

Comment: @mef_  No worries, totally understand.  If you can add anything else, that would be great.  I"m in US and will answer tomorrow.  In the meantime I think some others are interested in your question as well and will respond with something.  You've written it very well and that attracts peoples attention. I've rebuilt that engine before and have had similar issues with a Suzuki TL1000S, a Honda RC51 and a Suzuki SV1000S.

Comment: @DucatiKiller thanks! Unfortunately, it's all I can say. I will get to my bike next week and will check your suggestions with gear shifting and if there is something you can suggest me to check additionally to detect the problem with that sound, please write here.

Comment: I have similar issue with my sv650. My noise occurs around 1500 rpm and more so when cold. I can't pinpoint the sound, under the tank somewhere. My model has carbs, not injection. I'm wondering if there is some problem between idle jet and the main jet as I imagine 1500 rpm is about where the main jet kicks in? Given age of your bike I'm assuming yours is carb model too?

Comment: @PaulRobson  You can go here http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and ask your question.  You've accidentally answered another question and it's been moved to a comment.  Someone will flow to your question if you post it.

Comment: Can you upload a video so we can hear the sound when it happens?  You can upload the video to youtube or whattever and share the link in your question.  I think that will better illustrate what you are trying to describe verbally.

Comment: @DucatiKiller ok. I will record a video next week. I will be able to get my bike back only next week.

Comment: Are you going to be able to get that video posted?

Comment: Ive had bikes make noises like this. Most notably on a vtr1000 and ktm950, and especially when cold. I believe its something like detonation or pre-ignition due to a sudden increase in fuel and possibly coughing back through the carb. Once the revs pick up it goes away.

Comment: @DucatiKiller, sorry for the delay. I have updated original post, added video link.

Comment: Sorry I could not post a comment (not enough rep), that sounds like the carb is catching up. It may be a carb tunning issue. If you get on the gas more gradually does it happen?

Comment: My first thought is a faulty or loose engine mount.

Comment: Can you explain 'catching up'?

Comment: The starter clutch is under that cover. It's a one-way clutch that often features steel rollers that are supposed to jam between the crank and starter sprocket when starting, and then spin away when the engine starts. If this noise happens ONCE after starting, and then happens again only after the engine is stopped and restarted, than the starter clutch would get my vote.

Warn starter clutches only need replacing when they actually slip when starting, noise is generally not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not owning this motorcycle anymore. But anyway will post my experience of trying to solve this issue:

I went to different mechanics in my town and their opinions differ:

- One said that it's certainly is not okay. And he wants to take a look at the "guts"
- Others mostly said that it's okay and I'm throttle too fast
- This is the sound of the timing chain in the valve train and it's need to be fixed

I didn't fix it and sold motorcycle as is.

Comment: Thank you for providing closure.  Feel free to click the "accepted" tick, located to the left.